# Method update using nodejs sequelize with transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm working on personnal application of cookbook. I'm using for my backend, nodejs with ORM Sequelize V6.
I'm trying to code the update method. I'm using transaction. For create method, everything is fine.
In my model, I've got a RECIPES who has one to many relationship with STEPS and one to many relationship with INGREDIENTS
Firstable, in my update method I update my recipe after steps and ingredients. If errors occure, I want to have a rollback.
Update steps or ingredients consists to update one step/ingredient or create a new step/ingredient.
Errors can be a step or ingredient not found for example.

Here is my code.

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {

    const recipeId = req.params.id;

    const recipe = req.body;

    const ingredients = req.body.ingredients;

    const steps = req.body.steps;

    const update = (async () => {
        const r = await sequelize.transaction();
        const s = await sequelize.transaction();
        const i = await sequelize.transaction();

        try{
            // Update recipe
            await Recipe.update(recipe, {
                where: { id: recipeId },
                transaction: r
            });

            // Update steps
            if (steps) {
                await steps.forEach(step => {
                    if (step.id){
                        Step.update(step, {
                            where: {id: step.id},
                            transaction: s
                        });
                    } else {
                        step.recipeId = recipeId;
                        Step.create(step, {transaction: s});
                    }
                });
            }
            
            // Update ingredients
            if (ingredients) {
                await ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
                    if (ingredient.id){
                        Ingredient.update(ingredient, {
                            where: {id: ingredient.id},
                            transaction: i
                        });
                    } else {
                        ingredient.recipeId = recipeId;
                        Ingredient.create(ingredient, {transaction: i});
                    }
                });
            }
            

            // Persists.
            await r.commit();
            await s.commit();
            await i.commit();

            // Get the recipe updated to send to frontend
            await Recipe.findByPk(recipeId, {
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Step,
                        as: "steps",
                        attributes: { exclude: ["recipeId"]}
                    },
                    {
                        model: Ingredient,
                        as: "ingredients",
                        include: ["quantityType"],
                        attributes: { exclude: ["quantityTypeId", "recipeId"]}
                    },
                    "recipeType"
                ],
                attributes: { exclude: ["recipeTypeId"]},
            })
                .then(data => {
                    res.status(200).send(data);
                });

        } catch (err) {
            await r.rollBack();
            await s.rollBack();
            await i.rollBack();
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error occured whit update."
            })
        }
    })();

}
```

Thanks for any helps you can give.

Comment: And what is an issue?

Comment: If I test if a step or a ingredient is not existing, I send a 404 error and I want a rollback because recipe was persisted, but I haven't got a rollback.

Comment: Why don't you use just one transaction?

Comment: I'm trying right now ;-)